# How to insert a rowif a key does not exists with FluentMigrator

Tags: .net, merge, migration, upsert, fluent-migrator

I need to create a migration that add some rows, but only if they do not exists.

Currently, if there is a primary key conflict, because the row already exists, the migration fails.

I know how to create a table if the table does not exist, but I can not do the same for data.

Another option could be a upsert or merge operation, but didn't find how to do it with FluentMigrator (without executing a script)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly using the fluent interface. As you said you would either have to execute a script or write the sql commands in the migration itself and run it. Something like

```
public override void Up()
{
    var sqlCommand = string.Format([YOUR SQL COMMANDS]);
    Execute.Sql(sqlCommand);
}
```